# why $T^*=A_1T^×A_2^{-1}?$

Tags: functional-analysis

I have  some confusion in**Kreyszig** Book Functional analysis

My confusion given  below  marked in red box [image]

[image]

**My doubt** :why $T^*=A_1T^×A_2^{-1}?$

My attempt : It seem like $A_2^{-1}$ goes from  $H_2 \rightarrow H_2^{'}$ so image of $A_2^{-1}$ is $H_2'$

again $T^×$ from $ H_2' \to H_1'$ so image will be $H_1'$

that  mean $A_1(H_2'H_1')=T^*$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot really make sense of what you wrote in your attempt. What would $H_2'H_1'$ be?

The map $A_1T^\times A_2^{-1}$ maps $H_2\to H_2'\to H_1'\to H_1$, which with the right domain and codomain for $T^*$.

Let $x\in H_1$, $y\in H_2$. If $g\in H_2'$ is the functional $z\longmapsto \langle z,y\rangle$, then $A_2g=y$, and
$$
x_0=A_1T^\times A_2^{-1}y=A_1 T^\times g
$$
is the element in $H_1$ such that
$$
g(Tx)=(T^\times g)x=\langle x,x_0\rangle.
$$
So
$$
\langle A_1T^\times A_2^{-1}y,x\rangle=\langle x_0,x\rangle=\overline{ \langle x,x_0\rangle}
=\overline{g(Tx)}=\overline{\langle Tx,y\rangle}=\langle y,Tx\rangle.
$$
As this occurs for all $x\in H_1$, $y\in H_2$, we get that $T^*=A_1T^\times A_2^{-1}$.